# I use android.hardware.camera2, CDS enable 0 num_str 1 applied 0 stream_id 5

Tags: android

I'm using camera2 to record video,There was an error.

[image]

#### ImageReader

```
mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(largest.getWidth(), largest.getHeight(),ImageFormat.YUV_420_888, 5);
mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(mOnImageAvailableListener, null);
```

#### OnImageAvailableListener

```
private final ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener mOnImageAvailableListener
            = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {

        @Override
        public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
            Log.d("---------->", "mOnPreviewAvailableListener" + reader);
            try (Image image = reader.acquireNextImage()) {
                Image.Plane[] planes = image.getPlanes();
            }
        }

    };
```

#### PreviewRequestBuilder

```
mPreviewRequestBuilder.addTarget(mImageReader.getSurface());
```